# How to fetch a result of an int column data type from a table and if no record found select 0 as default in microsoft sql azure

Tags: sql, azure

How to fetch a result of an int column data type from a table and if no record found select 0 as default in microsoft sql azure

I had tried ISNULL but it does not work.

In case there is a table named student.

Column_Name              data_type

roll_nbr                    int

name                     varchar(30)

Select ISNULL(roll_nbr,0) FROM student where name = 'Sam;

I am expecting the query to return roll_nbr from the table if exists else return 0 as default if no rows is found.

Comment: Does azure support `coalesce`?

Comment: Do you mean if no record exists as in no row in the table or no record exists as in the value is `NULL`?

Comment: You tried ISNULL where? Edit question to show attempted code and result.

Comment: In case there is a table named student. 

Column Name   data_type 

roll_nbr                  int 


name                 varchar(30) 



Select ISNULL(roll_nbr,0) FROM student where name = 'Sam'; 


I am expecting the query to return roll_nbr from the table if exists else return 0 as default if no rows is found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your Azure Sql Query as below

**Using COALESCE()**

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT Roll_nbr FROM student WHERE NAME = 'Sam'), 0);
```

[(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9a6eaf/2)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9a6eaf/2)

The subquery will return the RollNumber if satisfies the `where` condition else it will return blank/null result. Use of `COALESCE` function on subquery will return first not null value.

**Using ISNULL()**

```
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT Roll_nbr FROM student WHERE NAME = 'Sam'), 0)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9a6eaf/6

> Instead of COALESCE() ISNULL() can be used.
> ISNULL function accepts only 2 arguments, used to replace null value and it is T-SQL function.
> COALEASCE function is ANSI SQL Standard based and it accepts 1-n arguments it returns first not null value.

Comment: Thank you very much this worked exactly the way i had expected the result to be.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 
CASE 
WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Student WHERE name = 'Sam') THEN roll_nbr
ELSE 0
END
FROM Student
```